# No result defined for action login.HrAction and result input, Error

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I have separate model class having no validation tag (@ not empty) named Searchmodel, but struts.xml complain for input tag on the jsp page  which calls this class. When input tag is placed in struts.xml project runs successfully but it puts validation on that jsp page, while I don't want validation on that page for default search feature.

SearchModel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class SearchModel {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "Employee_id")
private int Employee_id; 

@Column(name="Employee_Name")
private String Employee_Name;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="search" method="search" class="login.HrAction">
  <result name="success" >/Search.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Paste the stack trace here with logs

Answer (score 0):

I found that actually, name of jsp text area was same as db column i just changed it's named and expected result was there, preparing seprate model class without @notempty tag was right step but it was picking validation from other model class as due to of naming conflict in JSP page. I changed to unique name to communicate with perticular model class and it works